# How configure SonarQube to fail when a file coverage decreased

Tags: testing, sonarqube, test-coverage

do you know how can I configure SonarQube to fail when a file coverage decrease between a commit and another?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup Quality Gates for your SonarQube instance to reject code check in when the code coverage on your new code is less than a defined percentage.

[image]

Comment: Got it. I thought the Coverage on new code was the new code between a tag and another not the committed code. Thx

Comment: Any idea to fail the commit when the coverage of a single file (not in general as Coverage in new code) decrease?